# How can I install the older version of TFS for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I just updated TFS plugin in eclipse and cannot connect to TFS server anymore. The reason is that the server has an older version. So, I have to roll back to older  version but cannot find it in microsoft site. It just has the new version.

Does anybody know where I can get the older version(2012) of TFS?

Comment: Hold on - TEE is compatible with every version of TFS, back to 2005.  What errors are you actually getting?

Comment: The previous version of plugin that works is 11.0.0.12.

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this morning. I executed the following steps and it worked!!!!

1. Download the older version of TFS plugin (TFSEclipsePlugin-UpdateSiteArchive-11.0.0.1306.zip) from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661
2. Go to eclipse--> help-->install new software-->add--> choose atchive--> locate the download from step 1.-->Finish
3. A quick restart of eclipse, you are all set!!!

Saravana.

Comment: Can you report a bug for this?

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server 2012 with Update 3 can be found on the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38185).